# match first space on a line using sublime text and regular expressions

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

So regular expressions have always been tough for me. Im getting frustrated trying to find a regular expression that will select the first white space on a line. So then i can use sublime text to replace that with a /

If you could give a quick explanation that would help to

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In the spirit of @edi's answer, but with some explanation of what's happening. Match the beginning of the line with `^`, then look for a sequence of characters that are not whitespace with `[^\s]*` or `\S*` (the former may work in more editors, libraries, etc than the latter), then find the first whitespace character with `\s`. Putting these together, you have

```
^[^\s]*\s
```

You may want to group the non-whitespace and whitespace parts, so you can do the replacement you're talking about:

```
^([^\s]*)(\s)
```

Then the replacement pattern is just `\1/`

Comment: Thank you very much. Im starting to understand, but im not sure if ill ever get regular expressions completely.

Comment: How do you match just the first space? This appears to match the entire word plus the space:

Comment: @user798719, You can use `^[^\s]*\K\s` to match only the space. ("`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.")

Comment: @matt for find and replace purposes, this highlights the first space AND text preceding the first space on the line - I'd only want to replace the first space on the line. It also captures line breaks (where there is only a space on a line with no preceding content)

Answer (score 7):

You can use this regex.

```
^([^\s]*)\s
```