# Strip first space to end of line

Tags: regex, textmate

I am trying to strip the first space to the end of the line on each line of a text file in TextMate using the Find and Replace with Regular Expressions.

For example I want to replace the following line:

```
One, 2, Three!
```

With:

```
One,
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460211/match-first-space-on-a-line-using-sublime-text-and-regular-expressions) question, but I don't really understand how to use the accepted answer. It seems to be matching the whole line, and not the first space onwards.

Do I need to use a lookbehind to match the first space?

I started by trying:

```
^([^\s]*)\s.+$
```

Which matches the whole line if there is a space, but it there are no spaces on the line it matches two lines at a time.

When I do have the correct regex, do I just put it in the "Find" box and hit "Replace All" with the "Replace" box blank? I also don't really understand the "replacement pattern" syntax the answerer is talking about in the question I linked to.

Thanks.

**EDIT Aug 9, 2018:** This seems to be getting some views. If anyone is looking to do this with command-line tools, you can try:

```
awk '{print $1}' myfile.txt > output.txt
```

or to write back to the same file you can do:

```
awk '{print $1}' myfile.txt | sponge myfile.txt
```

This will take the first column before any whitespace, including tabs. To split on spaces specifically:

```
cat myfile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > output.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one single correct regex. There's any number of ways to do this. You can use a lookbehind, but there's no need to. How to actually *use* the regex also depends on how the pattern is designed - you might have to replace with nothing, or you might have to replace with a fancy text that's more complicated than the regex pattern itself.

---

Probably the easiest pattern to use is `.*(?:\n|$)` - replace with nothing. (Note the space in front of the dot.)

Another one would be `^(.*?) .*?$`, which needs the multi-line modifier to work. This one is trickier to use: you have to replace with `\1`. This *replacement pattern* references text that has been captured by the regex - in this case, all the text up to the first space. If you omitted this, all lines containing a space would be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Textmate, but [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) says that this should work:

```
^([^\s]*)([^\n]+)*$
```

The main difference being that instead of capturing any whitespace followed by any character, this only captures anything other than a newline character.